# How Do I make separate pages for my html website accessible from my navbar

Tags: html, css

I want to create different pages corresponding to the information on the nav bar that is accessible by clicking on the buttons. How is this achieved? Here is the code for the Nav Bar, additional information will be given on request.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#Home"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> search</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> More Info</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You're almost there, you just have to `href` the page in the `a` tag, you have to create new pages in the folder structure and use that instead of using `#` in your html.

Comment: you have to give the link of that page in " href="page.html" " under <a> tag. Like <a href="page.html">Page</a>

Comment: If you have multiple pages inside the folder then you can use like this <a href="../folder_name/page.html"Page</a>

Answer (score 1):

You link to other pages by placing the path to the files of those pages in `href`. Say if you have a file named `search.html` in the same folder, you would link to it using this `a tag`:

```html
<a href="search.html">search</a>
```

If the file is outside of the folder, you use `../` to navigate out of the folder. For example, if `contact.html` is in another folder called `pages`, you would do `../pages/contact.html`.

Answer (score -1):

if you have move one page to another page using html only, you can use href tag. "page.html" is a page which u have to move on button click here is code....
And make sure that page.html file should be present in same folder or  if not then change the path in href accordingly

```html
<button ><a href="page.html">Click me</a></button>
```

Comment: This is wrong! You have a `a` in your `button` but buttons must not have `a` tags as children. Check out [MDN Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), it sais "Permitted content: Phrasing content but there must be no Interactive content" but [`a` tags **are** interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content), especially if you have the `href` set. In other words: The browser does not know if it should handle the `button` or the `a` when you click on your button.